Can one use "this" when asking a question about a novel one has forgotten the title of?
In a different community (Science Fiction & Fantasy) I have asked a "story identification" question.
I started my question with the sentence

I read this great novel about 30 years ago.

Another user objected that the use of the word "this" was incorrect in this context. He wrote:

I do not think it is correct to use "this" when writing about something [as yet] unidentified.

My original reasoning in using "this" was that the novel was specific, unique, and thus well "defined" even though I was not at that point able to "identify" it myself.
In fact, I did remember enough details for others to find it rather rapidly.
So who is right ?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The use of this in your sentence is not incorrect but informal. Collins Cobuild English Usage in its section on this -  these (p716) states:

In conversation, many people use this  and these as determiners
even when they are mentioning people or things for the first time.

And then this woman came up to me and she said, 'I believe you
have a goddaughter called Celia Ravenscroft'.



However, this was not a conversation, but a written question. So maybe it is too informal in this context ?

It's technically wrong, but acceptable in the context of informal chat, whether spoken or online.

There are no definitive criteria for determining if a context is informal or not. I myself would have used the indefinite article in this context. But the use of this here is not "incorrect".

Thanks. So it is not incorrect, but informal. My wife who is a (retired) teacher of French language (in France) thinks that, in French, "un roman" would also have been better than "ce roman" in this context, but the latter is not strictly incorrect.

@Alfred. It's interesting to compare languages as to the acceptability of this use of this. In German it is less acceptable to write diesen Roman in place of einen Roman in such a sentence and context.

Thanks. I did learn some German some time ago, and I am less than fluent though I did manage to "survive" in Vienna a few years ago. But I am certainly not well versed enough to realise it would be less acceptable in German than in English or French.

I'd have bet that a pertinent reference couldn't be found. The sort of research that sets ELU apart as a resource. // Plenty of hits for '"this random guy asks me".

I recognise the example given (it's by Agatha Christie), and "this" has probably been used quite deliberately to add to the impression that the speaker is rather vague. Whether the author actually considered it correct usage is not at all clear.

Discursively. It's a deictic pronoun. Also, your example states right away who "this woman" is. The sample sentence is not pragmatically like that at all. There is no explanation and the question is not about grammar, really. I guess I'm the only one who explains why it is technically wrong when no context surrounds it.

Frankly, in practice, on a website where users post questions and answers, I'd OP's use of this is perfectly fine.  In my opinion, while technically correct, that comment is a bit pedantic.  (Now, if you were posting that question here on English SE, I'd say the comment is more applicable).

"That" would  make no sense but this in such uses is 100% idiomatic.

I once spent the winter living in this little cabin out in the middle of nowhere.
I can't really put my finger on it. It just had this "I'm the right puppy for you" quality, so I chose it over the others.
I once saw this movie where the inmates of a mental hospital are left behind when the town evacuates in advance of an enemy onslaught. It is set during World War I.

One of the main functions of determiners "the" and "this" is to present something as the focused topic of an utterance.  this is frequently used to that end when the topic is being mentioned for the first time and is understood to do exactly that, "closeness" to the speaker (in the non-locative deictic sense) having that practical meaning in such contexts.
The determiner the, on the other hand, would cause the listener to come up short:

I once spent the winter in the little cabin out in the middle of nowhere.

In a work of fiction, that would be taken as an instance of the story or account beginning in medias res, as we haven't been introduced yet to that cabin though it is being spoken of as if we have been previously introduced to it. But in a conversation, it would not be a good thing to do that, as you don't want the listener to stumble but want them to be able to "follow along" as you announce a topic and only after it has been announced ("a little cabin in the woods") does it become presented as your focus ("The cabin had one small window...").
You can reply irately to the space-trash who criticized you for it:

Oh yeah?  Well, take this, and this, and THIS!

In the movie version, each "this" would be accompanied by a punch from the hero: a jab, a cross, and  concluding with a walloping uppercut.
Then you get on your space-camel and ride off into the sol-set.

I (once) read a great novel, whose title escapes me …

@Mari-LouA  I once spent the winter living in this little cabin in the middle of nowhere.

I don't think your example in the answer nails it, in movies we see someone delivering punches to their adversary, the "this" belongs to the speaker: "Take this [punch] and take this [etc.] I'm not saying the answer wrong, it just the example doesn't captivate me.

@Mari-LouA  That was a joke, not an example. My example in the comment above about spending the winter in a cabin "nails it". I will add it to the answer.

I can't really put my finger on it. It just had this "I'm the right puppy for you" quality, so I chose it over the others. YES, because it refers to something in your own speech. That's not the OP's context.

@Lambie I know that example (unlike the other two) isn't precisely the OP's context, but it is a related use of this, so I've included it. What they have in common is that the speaker is expressing with "this" that they (the things "this" determines) are the speaker's focus and the speaker expects the listener to understand that even though the subject is being introduced for the first time in the utterance.

The use of this presupposes discursive or actual proximity to the referent.

These are good examples IMO

@Lambie  If, by "discursive proximity", you're refering to some kind of "nearness" that isn't physical but relating to the focus of an utterance, then I think we agree, as I say in the answer " ... 'closeness' to the speaker (in the deictic sense [by which I mean non-actual, non-locative]) having that practical meaning in such contexts"

Yes, and I structured my answer around that fact.

I would argue that it is not only grammatical, but serves a specific function.  Since "this" requires a referent, it can be used to implicitly announce and emphasise the referent in advance:

Greater love hath no man than this,  ➔ that a man lay down his
life for his friends.

In speech (or written speech), the act of communication itself – the sequence and cadence in which words are revealed – is part of the context, and it's just as valid to "point to" an upcoming idea as to a physical object in the room.
If you begin, "I read this great novel on a road trip to Disneyland with my family when I was 12...", then you have set up the question "What novel?".  The reader is alerted to expect a return to that question, even if you don't come to it directly, which aids clarity if they are reading the whole text straight through.  However, that is not necessarily how one reads an encyclopedia article (for example), so the idiom is less suited to formal use as a matter of style.

Yes, to the advance thing only he the speaker doesn't say what it is. So, without any additions to that simple utterance, no.

I mean, he doesn't have the ISBN, hence the question, but he identifies it clearly enough that it's obvious he's talking about Starship Troopers.

Remarks found in A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Langiuage (Quirk et al, 1985) on the use the demonstratives "this" and "that" as they apply to the usage under consideration.

(CoGEL § 17.46)
[…]
Since there is only one composition called the War Requiem by Britten, we have [12] but not [13] or [14]:
• The War Requiem of/by Britten (is a splendid work.) [12]
• *The War Requiem of Britten's [13]
• *One of Britten's War Requiems [14]
Yet, we are able, in apparent defiance of this statement, to use demonstratives as follows:
• that wife of mine [15]
• this War Requiem of Britten's [16]
In these instances, which always presuppose familiarity, the demonstratives are not being used in a directly defining role; rather, one might think of them as allowing
us to see wife and War Requiem as appositional, as members of a class of objects: 'This instance of Britten's works, namely, War Requiem'.
Even when more than one object  exists corresponding to the noun, the post-genitive phrase preceded by this should be regarded as having a generic partitive, eg:
• this hand of mine [17]
Example [17] should be interpreted not as 'this one of my (two) hands' but  rather as 'this part of my body that I call "hand"'.

The indications found in Practical English Usage (Michael Swann, second edition, 1995) refer to the usual contexts of use, but a note on "that" and "those" adds a precision about meaning.

(PEU § 565, n° 8 other uses)
Note the special use of this (with no demonstrative meaning) in conversational story-telling.
• There was this travelling salesman, you see,. And he wanted …
That/those can suggest that an experience is familiar to everybody.

I can't stand that perfume of hers.

This use is common in advertisements.
• When you get that empty feeling — break for a biscuit.
• *The perfect hobby for *those long winter evenings — astrology. Send for our free brochure.

This usage is correct, but informal ("always presupposes familiarity").

I read this great novel about 30 years ago.

The interpretation could then be "this instance of a book, which [I call / is called] a great novel".

The question "who is right?" is hard to answer because it could depends on context.  Many of the answers seem to go to "which is right?".
In view of the technical responses, one could say:
"You are right and the detractors are wrong".
In the context of language change, while the usage:
"I read this great novel about 30 years ago."
may be deemed correct, but I would never use it.  I would use:
"I read a great novel about 30 years ago." substituting "a" for "this".
I'm not sure that formal/informal quite covers it.  The first one sounds wrong to me.  Perhaps it's because it sounds like slang.  So we may get into the discussion of evolution of the language except for the fact that others have found justification for correctness.
Perhaps the speaker is concerned that the sentence "I read a great novel about 30 years ago", taken alone, may elicit the response: "Is that all?"; context should help alleviate that likely silly question.

The use of this presupposes discursive or actual proximity to the referent.
Question: "I read this great novel about 30 years ago.
Another user objected that the use of the word "this" was incorrect in this context. He wrote:
I do not think it is correct to use "this" when writing about something [as yet] unidentified." [bolding mine]
I agree, the indefinite determiner a would be used as it has not yet been identified:
I read a great novel about 30 years ago. It was about [whatever].
BUT it can also be:

I read this great novel about 30 years ago. It was about aliens and cowboys on ship in the Pacific.

That use of "this" refers to the speaker's actual experience, which is then revealed in the next statement. This question is really about deixis:

Common Frame of Reference Needed Without a common frame of reference between the speakers, the deixis on its own would be too
vague to be understood, as illustrated in this example from Edward
Finegan in "Language: Its Structure and Use."
Consider the following sentence addressed to a waiter by a restaurant
customer while pointing to items on a menu:    "I want this dish, this
dish, and this dish". To interpret this utterance, the waiter must have
information about who I refers to, about the time at which the
utterance is produced, and about what the three noun phrases this dish
refer to." (5th ed. Thomson, 2008)

See example
this can refer to something mentioned a speaker to references in his/her own speech but usually it does not refer to something in someone else speech. If two speakers are addressing each other, one might might use this if the context is very clear.

Speaker 1 (quoted in a slide): "We had a huge problem with our tap
water. It turned out to contain much too much lead. We were afraid our
kids would be poisoned".
Speaker 2 (speaking to Speaker 1 or
addressing a roomful of students, for example). Yes, we have found
this problem to be very serious in certain towns using the old water mains.

Summary: this as an actual thing (a referent) the speaker and listener are in contact with (the waiter example above) or this as a catch-all pronoun that refers to something in a speaker's own discourse or in close proximity to the speaker and listener(s) (the slide example). Both of these uses are deictic as they "point to the thing", actual thing or thing in speech (topic, situation).
